# Find records from one table which don't exist in another OR have a total sum of 0 for specific value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to select all customers that do have an entry in another table

OR

the sum of the field value "timer" equals 0 in the other table.

This is my approach:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  rS_customer AS c
LEFT JOIN 
  rS_customer_log AS l
    ON c.id = l.customerID
WHERE
  l.customerID IS NULL
OR 
  sum(l.timer) = 0
GROUP BY 
  l.customerID
```

I'm getting an error: "Invalid use of group function"

How can i resolve this?

Comment: I think it's more like an invalid use of the `sum` function but MySQL throws the error on Group By because it's the next line of code.

Comment: `GROUP BY   l.customerID HAVING   l.customerID IS NULL
OR 
  sum(l.timer) = 0`

Comment: @lad2025: your statement is valid, but it does not return the expected number of results. It only return 22 results, but it **should** return more than 2000. It does not return the customers that do not exists in rS_customer_log.

Comment: @lad2025 probably because of the GROUP BY statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `HAVING` if you have aggregates in conditions. That is the reason you are getting "Invalid use of group function" error.

For the wrong numbers, your join condition might be the cause. Try modifying the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM rS_customer WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT customerID FROM
```

rS_customer_log GROUP BY customerID HAVING sum(timer) <> 0);

This will fetch `rS_customer`s which do not exist in `rS_customer_log` or they exist and have sum of `timer` which is not equal to 0.

I hope this helps.